# Map Struct library code generation stops working randomly when I compile my quarkus app

Tags: java, compiler-errors, quarkus

I am using the following piece of code to make the conversion of my objects:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "jakarta", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
@ApplicationScoped
public interface FlightMapper {

    public FlightDTO toDTO(Flight flight);

    public Flight toDAO(FlightDTO flightDTO);

}
```

To be able to use it I imported (as written in the documentation) together with lombok:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
              <artifactId>quarkus-extension-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I compile my app with `quarkus build`.

Sometimes the build works, an my generated code appears in the path `target\generated-sources\annotations\...\domain\mapper\FlightMapperImpl.java`:
[image: Success scenario]

But sometimes without doing any change in my code, I do not get those setters generated, and therefore my code latter does not work. (The file is generated in the same location, just without the setters in both methods `toDTO` and `toDAO`):
[image: Fail scenario]

It sometimes gets fixed by recompiling or by reloading my vs code window (f1 -> developer: reload window).

I have no idea how can this behave different randomly. When it fails I get this warning:

```java
[INFO] --- compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ project ---
[INFO] Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files with javac [debug release 17] to target\classes
[WARNING] Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -proc:none to disable annotation processing or -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus:3.7.4:generate-code-tests (default) @ project ---
```

NOTE: It also happens with `quarkus dev`, again randomly.

Comment: I think the annotation @ApplicationScoped is not necessary, maybe it is causing the problem.

Comment: @DhiogoBoza I just tried, but still the same, randomly some builds fail because the setters are not there. What is even more strange, I have many mappers and in some of them works and some of them not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue could come from what is described: [in this querstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63620377/using-mapstruct-together-with-lombok-under-quarkus)

After changing the order to put lombok first in the POM and a clean install it seems it is working as expected:

```xml
<annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
              <artifactId>quarkus-extension-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
```